# Keyframe does not apply to the selected bone

Tags: rigging

[image]

I made eye movements using shape key and driver.

Next, I lip synced using the rhubarb add-on.

Then I tried to give model a blink, but the keyframe is applied to only one bone.

For what reason does it apply to only one bone?

If I put hands down and give them a keyframe, both of them work, but don't give them to pupils and eyelids.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values that we see in the *N panel > Transform* are not related to the 2 selected bones, but only to the active one. If you keyframe in the *N panel > Transform* instead of keyframing in the 3D view, only the *Transform* values of the active bone will be saved. So I guess you need to keyframe in the 3D view.

Test on your own file:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by giving a keyframe on a 3d view? Do you mean pressing the i key on the 3d view and pressing the location? it's not working... And giving the keyframe to the n-panel is a method that I often use.

Comment: Yes press i on the 3D view. You often keyframe several bones in the N panel?

Comment: Pressing i in 3d view also applies to only one bone. I used to do it well on the panel, but I can't do it well today. I don't know if it's because of Rhubarb add-on. Thank you

Comment: I've just tested on your own file and it works fine for me

Comment: I see... If there is no problem with the file, I think the blender I use is wrong. I've reinstalled and factory reset, but I don't know why

Comment: I think what Moonbot said is correct. I'm sorry.